# how to initialize spring application context when eclipse jetty server startup

Tags: java, spring, jetty, jax-ws

We have a web project based on JAX-WS, I have some code which involves spring, and I need to initialize the spring context within server startup. However it doesn't make sense.

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class JettyServer2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(9000);
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/*");
        context.addServlet(servlet, "/*");
        context.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler());
        try {
            server.start();
            //System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "test");
            //try to initialize spring context here
            server.join();
        } finally {
            server.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to initialize system property which I commented out in above code, however, both the system property and the spring context initialization don't work. I'm guessing they are running in different jvm and current thread is dead after server.destroy().

Could anyone help to figure out why spring context initialization doesn't work, and let me know how to make it on the right way?

The initialization code is just like:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanConfig.class);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you use Spring boot ?

Comment: @javaguy  It's a good suggestion, but it's a big task because the previous code is not written by myself.